# store div items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make stacks, for each stack i have a div container. In that container are a lot of divs, the items for the stack.

I want to use 'classes' (i know javascript don't really has them).

First, i get the containers and from here i pass it.

```
var stacks = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.stackContainer').each(function(containerIndex) {
        //stacks[containerIndex] = $(this);
        $(this).css('z-index', containerIndex);
        stacks.push(new StackMedia($(this)));
    });

});
```

Now comes the hard part (for me).
In the StackMedia i want to store the items, this are just divs with a stackItem class (and it shouldn't turn into a Singleton).

I tried a lot of stuff, atm i get can't find variable items.

```
function StackMedia (container) { //, x, y, overlapX, overlapY
    this.container = container;
    //this.x = x;
    //this.y = y;
    //this.overlapX = overlapX;
    //this.overlapY = overlapY;

    this.items = container.find('.stackItem');
    console.log(items.length);

    //var elems = container.find('.stackItem'); 
    //var $items = jQuery.makeArray(elems);

    /*
    for(var i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
        console.log($items[i]);
        $items[i].css('top', i * 10).css('left', i * 10);

    }
    */

    /*
    this.items = [];

    container.find('.stackItem').each(function(itemIndex) {
        //console.log($(this));
        //items = $(this);
        this.items.push("test");
    });
    */

    /*
    items = container.find('.stackItem');
    */



}
```

How can i achieve what i want?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean when you say you don't want it to be a singleton? Are you implying that you want it to have a reference to the StackMedia object?

Comment: let's say i have 3 stacks, then the items[] array for each stack should hold different things. Not that when i update one that it updates in all stacks. (In other words i must be able to create more instances). Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with these elements? What is not working?

Comment: A shit, just found what i did wrong, i have:
`console.log(items.length);` and it should have been `console.log(this.items.length);` This took me so long... :( I'm better at java then javascript so i have stupid minor mistakes sometimes.